# Prove that $ A^n := \{ a^n : a \in A \}$ and $A_n := \{ g: g \in A : g^n = 1 \} $ are characteristic subgroups of $A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**The Statement of the Problem:**

Let $A$ be an abelian group and $n$ a positive integer. Prove that

$$ A^n := \{ a^n : a \in A \} $$

$$ \text{and} $$

$$ A_n := \{ g: g \in A : g^n = 1 \} $$

are characteristic subgroups of $A$.

**Where I Am:**

So, it looks like what I want to show is that $\forall \phi \in \text{Auto}(A), \phi (A^n) = A^n$. If I understand correctly, the case of *inner* automorphisms is clear:

$$ \phi _ a (a^n) = aa^na^{-1} = aa^{-1}a^n = a^n .$$

But, is there some way to represent an arbitrary automorphism and just "check" it? Or is this not as simple as I've hoped (or even simpler!)?

EDIT: I've got an idea for the first one, but I don't think it's correct...

$a^n = aaa...a$, i.e., the product of $n$ $a$'s. Now, because $\phi$ is a homomorphism:

$$ \phi (a^n) = \phi (aaa...a) = \phi(a)\phi(a)\phi(a)...\phi(a). $$

And because $\phi$ is bijective:

$$ \phi^{-1}[\phi(a)\phi(a)\phi(a)...\phi(a)] = aaa...a = a^n. $$

Q.E.D?

Comment: It's trivially true of inner automorphisms: There's only the identity, for abelian groups! But yes, just pick a "generic automorphism" (i.e., bijection $\varphi :A \to A$ satisfying $\varphi(xy) = \varphi(x)\varphi(y)$), and see what happens.

Comment: @pjs36 Ah. Ok. Well, I worked it for a bit and added an edit. I'm not too confident in it, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's *easier* (algebraically) than you're making it, but we have to think more if we want less algebra. I *think* you have the big idea, but I wouldn't say it's entirely airtight $\ddot\smile$.

At least, I think the big idea of yours is that $\phi(a^n) \in A^n$, so $\phi(A^n) \subseteq A^n$. *Mentioning* this would be good: "Since $\phi(a) \in A$, we have that $\phi(a^n) = \phi(a)^n \in A^n$," for example.

I'm not sure you showed the reverse containment though, this is where the commentary is really important. To show that $A^n \subseteq \phi(A^n)$, show that every $a^n$ can be written as an image under $\phi$ of some $n$th power: $$a^n = \phi\big(\underbrace{\phi^{-1}(a)^n}_{\in A^n}\big) \in \phi(A^n).$$ But that was *super* confusing for me to figure out exactly what needed written down!

---

An alternative:

You already showed that $\phi(a^n) = \phi(a)^n$, and I would use that.

So, if $A^n = \{a^n : a \in A\}$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\phi(A^n) 
&= \{\phi(a^n) : a \in A\} \tag{definition of image} \\
&= \{\phi(a)^n: a \in A\} \tag{property of homomorphisms}\\
&= A^n
\end{align*}

where the latest equality is simply because $\phi: A \to A$ is a bijection; we have $$A = \{a: a \in A\} = \{\phi(a): a \in A\},$$

and so $\{\phi(a)^n : a \in A\}$ must be $\{a^n : a \in A\}$, just a bit "mixed up" perhaps (as $a$ runs through $A,\ \phi(a)$ does too).